# Matplotlib, s must be scalar

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm trying to make a scatterplot a size defined in a varible I get from a DataFrame. When I run the code my error message says: ''ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y''. Anyone know what to do? I have checked with my DataFrame so it got nothing to do with that.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index

data = pd.read_csv('shotmaps.csv')

data['x-coordinate'] = data['x-coordinate'].astype('float64')
data['y-coordinate'] = data['y-coordinate'].astype('float64')
data['xG'] = data['xG'].astype('float64')

home_team = data.loc[data["H/A"] == "h"]
away_team = data.loc[data["H/A"] == "a"]

plt.scatter(home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['x-coordinate']*120, 
home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['y-coordinate']*80, c = '#ea6969', s=home_team['xG']) 

plt.scatter(120-away_team[away_team['Result']!='Goal']['x-coordinate']*120, 
away_team[away_team['Result']!='Goal']['y-coordinate']*80, c = 'yellow', s=away_team['xG'])
```

Comment: ¿¿ Had you checked the shapes of `home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['x-coordinate']` and `home_team['xG']` ??  I suspect that you must apply the same filtering also to the `xG` column, `home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['xG']` but it's just a guess, you should edit your question to add details

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggested, `s` - which is `home_team['xG']` (or away_team) can be either a scalar or the same size of x and y.

For the line:
`plt.scatter(home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['x-coordinate']*120,  home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['y-coordinate']*80, c = '#ea6969', s=home_team['xG']`

your `x` variable is `home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['x-coordinate']*120`. The size of it is "all the rows where Result is different than Goal". Your `y` variable is the same size. But `s`? you supply the whole `xG` for it, therefore it is not in the same size as `x` and `y` (it includes all rows, not only where the Result is different from "Goal").

You should probably supply it with `s=home_team[home_team['Result']!='Goal']['xG']` (or in short `s=home_team.loc[home_team['Result']!='Goal', 'xG']`. That way it takes only the values of `xG` columns where "Result" is different than "Goal".

Same for the second line when plotting `away_team`.

P.S - for next time, supply a simple dataframe so the community can reproduce your problem. It's hard to help without it, although in this case it was possible